# Why do we have no 'Stellar' questions?

Tags: discussion, badges

How on earth is anyone ever going to get this badge?

[Stellar Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/stellar-question)

> Question favorited by 100 users. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

On StackOverflow there have been [4.3k Stellar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question) badges awarded.

**Why none on SciFi?**

Comment: Because there are lots more users on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Progress toward Stellar](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/431417/progress-towards-favorite-question-and-stellar-question-badges)

Comment: Holy crap, most of those are Harry potter questions.

Answer (score 11):

### There are two factors at play here

1. Number of users. As mentioned in Valorum’s answer, Stack Overflow has a hundred times as many users as we do.
2. Usefulness of answers. On a site like Stackoverflow or Mathematics, you might need to go back and reference an answer multiple times for homework, coding, and so forth—*or* because you think it’s cool (or because you want to put a bounty on it, etc). On Science Fiction and Fantasy, you mainly *only* star it because you think it’s cool. This might help explain why Academia, with fewer users, for example, has [two](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question) stellar question badges awarded. Similarly, Raspberry Pi is notably smaller, but [two questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question) there have at least 100 stars— since many people need reminding on [how to back up their Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-do-i-backup-my-raspberry-pi).

Someone *will* eventually get the badge here, as the stars accumulate, but it might take while.

Comment: Honestly, why are they trying to use the same formula for every spin off site on Stack?

Comment: There's also the fact that on Raspberry Pi:SE **everyone owns a Pi** whereas on SFF:SE, not everyone is into Star Trek, etc.

Comment: @Valorum - Sure. That’s another factor contributing to our relative uselessness: fragmentation.

Comment: Apparently, though, there are [quite a few people](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1520/31394) who find answers about some series of nonsense films inordinately useful. I can't imagine why,

Comment: @Randal’Thor - That’s one of the more-starred answers, I imagine, because it’s useful to people who haven’t watched the *Star Wars* films and want the list on hand. The number of views can’t hurt, either.

Comment: @Valorum lol, nice point.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest it's mostly down to the size of the user-base

Stack Overflow = **5.9m users.**
SFF:SE = **40k users**

It's also the reason why it's possible for [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) to have 15,000 upvotes and over 7000 favourites (with an answer that has 22,000 upvotes).

Answer (score 1):

### We have one now.

[What order should Asimov's Foundation series be read in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2335/102999) reached 100 users who favorited it [in April of last year](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/stellar-question?userid=1107).

Comment: That post has gotten 5 gold badges if I remember correctly.

Comment: Worthy noting that this was largely down to a campaign to engineer a stellar question rather than it just picking up all of these votes organically.